# Add a continuous scale ggplot bar with stat_summary(fun.y = "mean")

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a bar chart that summarizes the mean of my data by factor. Then I want to make the fill color of the bars reflect the value of the mean. I can't get the fill to work. I think it's something with `stat_summary()`.

Using the `diamonds` dataset:

```
p <- ggplot(data = diamonds,
                 aes(x = cut, y = price, fill = price)) + 
        stat_summary(fun.y = "mean", geom= "bar" )
p
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach:

```
p <- ggplot(data = diamonds,
            aes(x = cut, y = price)) + 
         stat_summary(fun.y = "mean", geom= "bar", aes(fill = ..y..))
```

[image]

When you call stat summary on some data the transformed data does not have the same names as the original data, you can check this by making a ggplot object and calling `ggplot_build` on it.

```
head(ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]])
     fill x group ymin        y     ymax PANEL xmin xmax colour size linetype alpha
1 #4894D0 1     1    0 4358.758 4358.758     1 0.55 1.45     NA  0.5        1    NA
2 #2D5F89 2     2    0 3928.864 3928.864     1 1.55 2.45     NA  0.5        1    NA
3 #306592 3     3    0 3981.760 3981.760     1 2.55 3.45     NA  0.5        1    NA
4 #56B1F7 4     4    0 4584.258 4584.258     1 3.55 4.45     NA  0.5        1    NA
5 #132B43 5     5    0 3457.542 3457.542     1 4.55 5.45     NA  0.5        1    NA
```

you can use some of the variables defined in this data as a mapping by using the syntax `..variable..` (like `..y..`).